# jQuery's equivalent to 'enabling' an input

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have a disabled text input that loads as:

```
<input type="text" name="Email<%=i %>" disabled="disabled" />
```

I'd like the jQuery statement that enables it. Seems like:

```
$("email0").attr("enabled");
```

should be close but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) the *disabled* attribute:

```
$("input[name=email0]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Note that the selector `"email0"` in your example will not match anything, you are looking for an `input` element that has a `name` attribute containing `"email0"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) like this:

```
$("input").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Or [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
$("input").attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("email0").attr("enabled");
```

… would get the value of the enabled attribute, which would be undefined since there isn't one.

You want:

```
$("email0").removeAttr("disabled");
```